# Rays emanating from a point on the surface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics, emission

I am trying to create an effect in cycles (like the attached photo), where points on the surface emit rays (like god-rays). I have tried adding a spot light at the location where I want this, along with a principled volume to the world (setting the density to ~0.1). However, the whole scene becomes foggy and the effect is not really produced.

Can someone please show me a way to create this (just the rays)?
[image]

Comment: Volume scatter can be even lower than 0.1 try 0.05 or less, also make the light size small and increase the power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple box for the volume with the following texture:

[image]

Comment: Awesome :) My I ask to share also blend (sure not problem to reconstruct from image, just as time saver). Thank you

Comment: @Secrop Thanks for the solution. Could you explain a bit what the 'Normalize' and 'Length' are supposed to do?

Comment: @koroma, the 'Normalize' just makes every coordinate to be it's projection onto the unit sphere (the ray like stuff). 'Lenght' is just used as a falloff.

Comment: @vklidu, blend file long gone. just did it to illustrate, and one can do it in less than 5 minutes.